# Is binary log purging done by expire_logs_days equivalent to PURGE BINARY LOGS?

Tags: mysql, replication, logs

In a MySQL replication environment where replication is done with binary logs, if you run `PURGE BINARY LOGS` on the master, the server will not delete logs that are currently being replicated by a slave according to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/purge-binary-logs.html):

> This statement is safe to run while slaves are replicating. You need not stop them. If you have an active slave that currently is reading one of the log files you are trying to delete, this statement does not delete the log file that is in use or any log files later than that one, but it deletes any earlier log files.

I couldn't find however any description of whether or not the log purging done by setting the `expire_logs_days` variable has the same behaviour, e.g. it will not touch logs that are currently being replicated.

Can anyone tell me if the two are equivalent?

Comment: Good question; hope you get an answer.